# How to use delegate as argument in function using reflection

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, delegates, arguments

I have a class that has method for get value from specific function (sin(x)) and method for get value from any function using delegate.

```
namespace ValueFunctionFinder {

public delegate double SomeFunction(double arg);

public class ValueFunctionFinderClass
{
    public double GetValue(double x)
    {
        double y = Math.Sin(x);
        return y;
    }

    public double GetValueDel(double x, SomeFunction function)
    {
        double y = function(x);
        return y;
    }

}
```

I use this class in my main:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ValueFunctionFinderClass finder = new ValueFunctionFinderClass();

    double x = Math.Sin(Math.PI / 6);
    // find value from specific function 
    double y = finder.GetValue(x);
    Console.WriteLine($"Sin(PI/6) = {y}");

    // find value from any function
    SomeFunction function = Math.Sin;
    y = finder.GetValueDel(x, function);
    Console.WriteLine($"Sin(PI/6) = {y}");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

In another project I want to use it again with Reflection:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("ValueFunctionFinder");
    Type functionFinderType = assembly.GetType("ValueFunctionFinder.ValueFunctionFinderClass");
    object functionFinderObj = Activator.CreateInstance(functionFinderType);

    // find value from specific function using Reflection
    MethodInfo getValueMethodInfo = functionFinderType.GetMethod("GetValue");
    double x = Math.Sin(Math.PI / 6);
    object y = getValueMethodInfo.Invoke(functionFinderObj, new object[] { x });
    Console.WriteLine($"Sin(PI/6) = {y}"); // it works OK

    // find value from any function with Reflection
    Type someFunctionType =    assembly.GetType("ValueFunctionFinder.SomeFunction");

    // I should use smth like this:
    // **********************************************
    // dynamic creation of delegate
    //Delegate del = Delegate.CreateDelegate(someFunctionType, someMethodInfo); // what kind of methodInfo shoul I use?
    // dynamic use of delegate
    //object function = del.DynamicInvoke(arguments); // what kind of arguments? Math.Sin?
    // **********************************************
    MethodInfo getValueDelMethodInfo = functionFinderType.GetMethod("GetValueDel");
    //y = getValueDelMethodInfo.Invoke(functionFinderObj, new object[] {x, function});
    Console.WriteLine($"Sin(PI/6) = {y}"); // how do this?
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I have read [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/53cz7sc6(v=vs.110).aspx) and this resource, but coudn't understand how to use delegate as argument in function, using reflection.

Comment: Why do you need your own method to do nothing but invoke a delegate?  Just invoke the delegate directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SomeFunction function = Math.Sin;
```

is a shortcut for

```
SomeFunction function = new SomeFunction(Math.Sin);
```

and reflection can do this for us with the [MethodInfo.CreateDelegate method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194402(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var getValueDelMethod = functionFinderType.GetMethod("GetValueDel");

// create a delegate to the target method of the desired type
var delegateType = typeof(SomeFunction);
var sinMethod = typeof(Math).GetMethod(nameof(Math.Sin));
var delegateObj = sinMethod.CreateDelegate(delegateType);

var result = getValueDelMethod.Invoke(functionFinderObj, new object[] {x, delegateObj});
```

Comment: Great! It's what I needed! Thank you, thehennyy.